# Filter dataset into two portions

Tags: c#, filter, dataset

Guys I have a dataset containing information as:

```
                          UserID  int,document nvarchar(100)
```

I know dataset will be containg information with data belonging to two users e.g ,data will contain userID as 1 or 2. Now I want to filter dataset twice. First I want all rows containing userID as 1 and secondly I want All rows containg UserID as 2.But UserId's are dynamic.this is confirmed that data will be for only two users . Now my question is how to filter this data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want filter a list by specific creteria?

Lets say you have the struct user:

```
struct User
{
    int id;
    string document;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public string Document
    {
        get { return document; }
    }
    public User(int id, string document)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.document = document;
    }
}
```

So you can filter your data like this using LINQ:

```
User[] data = new User[] {
            new User(1, "first"),
            new User(1, "second"),
            new User(1, "third"),
            new User(2, "first"),
            new User(2, "second"),
            new User(2, "third"),

        };
        //Get all data with userID = 1
        User[] userID1 = data.Where(user => user.Id == 1).ToArray();

        //Get all data with userID = 2
        User[] userID2 = data.Where(user => user.Id == 2).ToArray();
```

If thats not your question, please specify your problem.

### edit:

If you dont know which ids in the dataset, you could group the data by the userID:

```
var userData = data.GroupBy(user => user.Id).ToArray();
foreach (var item in userData)
{
    var arr = item.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Dear I dotnt know UserID column data it can be anything.But its sure whole datatable will contain only two userID's.Eg, some times userID can be 1 and 2 while other time userID column will contain data for UserID 5 and 6.